# Invert specific bits using bitwise NOT (no XOR)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How can I use Bitwise Not to invert specific bits for x number? I know we can do this use XOR and mask but question requires use NOT.

I need to invert a group of bits starting at a given position. The variable inside the function includes original value, position wants to start and width = number of bits I want to invert.

I use the shift bit to start from a given position but how can I ensure only x number of bits are inverted using NOT Bitwise function?

Comment: Bitwise NOT takes a single parameter and inverts _all_ the bits of that parameter. It is, therefore, not an appropriate solution for the problem regardless of what the "question" requires.

Comment: I ran google on part of your question "use Bitwise Not to invert specific bits" and the first result tells exactly how to do it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 6):

Definition of xor: `a ^ b <--> (a & ~b) | (~a & b)`

```
unsigned x = 0x0F;
unsigned mask = 0x44;  // Selected bits to invert

unsigned selected_x_bits_inverted = (x & ~mask) | (~x & mask);
printf("%02X\n", selected_x_bits_inverted);
// 4B
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be:

First, extract them into y:

```
y = x & mask
```

Then, invert y and get only the bits you need:

```
y = ~y & mask
```

Clear the bits extracted from x:

```
x = x & (~mask)
```

OR those 2 numbers to get the result:

```
x = x | y
```

Note that every bit that has to be inverted is 1 in mask. Even if I used other bitwise operators, the actual bit flipping is done by a bitwise not. Also, I don't think it is possible to achieve this result without using some other binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

This function will invert 'width' number of bits of number 'num' from position 'pos'

```
int invert(int num, int pos, int width)
{

  int mask = (~((~0) << width)) << pos;
  num = (~(num & mask)) & mask);

}
```